# AJAX like button in PHP PDO is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I am following a series of tutorials on youtube by howcode. It is about making a social network. When it comes to like/comment, he uses an api. However, this is not working for me, I want to use a normal ajax. I want to submit a like request from:

```
<form>
if (!DB::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$post['id'], ':userid'=>$userid))) {
               echo "<input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' data-id=".$post['id'].">";
    } else {
    echo "<input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike' data-id=".$post['id'].">";
    }
    echo "<span>".$post['likes']." likes</span>
    </form>
```

reaching this ajax:

```
   $('[data-id]').click(function() {
            var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    processData: false,
                    //ScontentType: "application/json",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(r) {
                            console.log("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
                    },
                    error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r)
                    }
            });
    });
```

then going here:

```
if (isset($_GET['postid'])) {
     Post::likePost($_GET['postid'], $userid);
 }
```

Comment: i dont know where i am going wrong

Comment: And what are the errors?

Comment: jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.m._evalUrl (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)

Comment: Your selector syntax is one of the things definitely wrong so your click function will not work.

Comment: How are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: yes...that is how the guy did it using an api https://github.com/howCodeORG/Social-Network/blob/Part39/index.html

Comment: @JayBlanchard <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a selector i.e class or an id. to the element you want to use the jquery selector on & then bind the event on that selector. Please check the below updates to your code. Also you need to add the `preventDefault` method to prevent the original event of that selector.

```
<form>
    if (!DB::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$post['id'], ':userid'=>$userid))) {
          echo "<input class = "submit-class" type='submit' name='like' value='Like' data-id=".$post['id'].">";
    } else {
         echo "<input class = "submit-class" type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike' data-id=".$post['id'].">";
    }
    echo "<span>".$post['likes']." likes</span>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$('.submit-class').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    processData: false,
                    //ScontentType: "application/json",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(r) {
                            console.log("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
                    },
                    error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r)
                    }
            });
    });
```

Comment: i was including the jquery wrong...now no errors...but the page still refresh after every click

Comment: you need to add `e.preventDefault();` . make sure to update it to `$('.submit-class').click(function(e) {`

Comment: hhhhhhhhhh is now appearing...so it worked...will modify the success function now! thanks!!!

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ahh Sorry for that. I have updated the answer, will keep that in mind for future.